# How to get RSSI of Bluetooth, specfically HC-05

Tags: power, signal, bluetooth

We purchased a Bluetooth device [EGBT-045MS](http://www.rasmicro.com/Bluetooth/EGBT-045MS-046S%20Bluetooth%20Module%20Manual%20rev%201r0.pdf) in hope that we will be able to get its RSSI. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

First you send an INQM command (Set inquiry access mode), e.g.

```
AT+INQM=1,9,48
```

1 specifies access mode RSSI, 9 specifies the max # of devices to be discovered, and 48 is a timeout value

Follow this by a INQ command (Query Nearby Discoverable Devices)

```
AT+INQ
```

It will respond with lines like:

```
+INQ:1234:56:0,1F1F,FFC0
```

(up to nine responses in this case, set by the INQM command).  Last entry is followed by an OK.

The first parameter is the address of the discovered Bluetooth device; all digits are hexadecimal.  As shown here, it is in what is called NAP:UAP:LAP format.

The middle parameter is a type field.

The last parameter in the returned string is the RSSI value.  Different makers of Bluetooth modules encode the RSSI value in different ways. From what I can tell looking at other documents, this module always returns 16-bit negative numbers in the range FF80 (or maybe FFC0) to FFFF.  So a higher number probably means a high signal strength.

Comment: On my HC-05 the command must be AT+INQM=1,9,48 (add an equals sign)

Comment: @Houen You are correct, I left off the = sign.  I've updated my answer.  Thanks.